# Ionic 2 - Multiple menu at the same time (right - left)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**THE SITUATION**:

I have a working right menu in my Ionic 2 app. I need to add a left menu.
I have tried but was unsuccessfull so far.
This is my attempt:

**THE CODE**:

With this code the right menu is properly working, but it doesn't appear the left menu.

**app.html:**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" id="menu1">

    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
                {{p.title}}
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

</ion-menu>


<ion-menu [content]="content" id="menu2">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="danger">
      <ion-title>Menu 2</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
        Close Menu 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
constructor(
        public platform: Platform,
        public menu: MenuController
    ) {
        this.initializeApp();

        this.pages = [
            { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
            { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage },
        ];

        this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1');
        this.menu.enable(true, 'menu2');
    }
```

**THE QUESTION**:

How can I have two menu - left and right - properly working at the same time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just like you can see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/#multiple-menus-on-different-sides), you need to add `side="left"` and `side="right"` like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu1">...</ion-menu>
```

And

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">...</ion-menu>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks **@johnnyfittizio** for your comments! I've made the changes you mentioned there (please edit this answer if I forgot something).

So basically we just need to add both menus (for instance, in the `app.html` page) like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu1">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu1" detail-none>
        Close Menu 1
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item  menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
        Close Menu 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>



<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

Then we need to add both menu buttons in the header like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="left" start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      HomePage
    </ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="right" end>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <p>Home page</p>

</ion-content>
```

Please notice that each button has the `menuToggle="left"` or `menuToggle="right"` property to be able to toggle the proper menu.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is not working yet unfortunately. There is perhaps something else?

Comment: If you create two buttons (just for testing) and in the click event you add `this.menu.toggle('right');` and in the other one ``this.menu.toggle('left');``. Does it show both menus?

Comment: yeah! clicking on the right button it appears the right menu. So the only thing is that I cannot see the right menu icon in the header.. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Hmm, so we're close! I've created a plunker, (and added the code in the answer as well), could you please check if there's anything different between the plunker and your code?

Comment: Thank you very much! We are almost there! I have the two buttons now in the header. But I don't know why they are both at the right side. I have checked all you plunker thanks! But when I run i cannot see the outcome. Anyway I am just checking how to properly put the menu buttons. Then i will mark as correct answer.

Comment: Yeah I fix that! Can you just edit your answer please including ion-button directive inside both buttons in the view. Without that the two buttons don't have the proper style and positioning. With that all is properly working now!

Comment: Great! did you try by using the `start` and `end` attributes?

Comment: Sorry :) it's me again. I noticed two things. 1. this.menu.enable is irrelevant. Without that it works everything just fine. So is not even necessary to load the MenuController in the page component. 2. In the page view I had to wrap the ion-toolbar of the menu inside a <ion-header> to have proper style. Otherwise I had some margin-top problem with the menu content. Source solution: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-rc-1-ion-menu-missing-margin-top-on-scroll-content/67137

Comment: I'll update the answer and the plunker. Sorry for the ion-header issue, the plunker uses the beta version of Ionic2, and I didn't remember that when I copied the code here :)

Comment: No problem! The last thing is that at this point we don't need anymore any ID for the menu. Should be all :)

Comment: Great! Btw, thanks for taking the time to help me improving the answer :)

Comment: Soooory dude! I am new to Ionic2 and there many things far from obvious for me. We do need the id="menu1" and id="menu2". In order to get the proper menuClose="menu1" menuClose="menu2" working.