# How toggle button bind to menus?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

To put a toggle button to a page we use `menuToggle` director. But if I want to put two or three menus in a page, what should I do? On the other word, how toggle of a button detects which menu should open on click?

Note: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802202/ionic-2-multiple-menu-at-the-same-time-right-left) not describes how toggle works, it just says about  `menuToggle="right"` or `menuToggle="left"`. But if I have two menu on left,  what should I write code to bind button and menu together?

Menu 1:

```
<ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
  <button ion-button menuToggle="left">Toggle Menu</button>

  <ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <p>some menu content</p>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menuClose detail-none>Close Menu</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
```

Menu 2:

```
  <button ion-button menuToggle="left">Toggle Menu2</button>

  <ion-menu [content]="mycontent" side="right">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <p>some menu content 2</p>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menuClose detail-none>Close Menu2</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
```

Menu 3:

```
  <button ion-button menuToggle="right">Toggle Menu2</button>

  <ion-menu [content]="mycontent" side="right">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <p>some menu content 3</p>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menuClose detail-none>Close Menu2</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 - Multiple menu at the same time (right - left)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802202/ionic-2-multiple-menu-at-the-same-time-right-left)

Comment: @suraj It's only an example. I want to know the mechanism of menus in ionic2 to make complex ones. For example if I have 2 menu on left and one in right how should I make it?

Comment: Does `menuToggle="menuId"` or `menuOpen="menuId` work? No time to check atm

Comment: @Ivaro18 Yes... they work... But how? I don't know :)

Comment: well if that's the case, just bind an `id` value to your `<ion-menu>` and pass that in the button

Answer (score 0):

First try binding the id to a toggle option like so

`<ion-menu id="menu1">` and `<button menuToggle="menu1">` OR `<button menuOpen="menu1">`

---

If that doesn't work you use the following workaround using `MenuController` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/MenuController/)

If you have 2 menu's with id's

`<ion-menu id="menu1">` and `<ion-menu id="menu2">` you can then make a button

`<button (click)="openMenu('menu1')">Open menu 1</button>`

And in your `ts` just create your menuController and open the selected menu

```
constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {}

openMenu(menuId: string) {
   this.menuCtrl.open(menuId);
}

closeMenu(menuId: string) {
   this.menuCtrl.close(menuId);
}
```